# Affix riddle with pharaoh

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, language, history

> In the tongue of a beautiful pharaoh
>   for a prefix this word has a small O.
>   For a suffix small N,
>   for an infix small M,
>   and, itself, it is only a small O.

What is the word?

Comment: Is it the moon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a prefix this word has a small O

> O - the symbol for oxygen and an atom of this is small.

For a suffix small N

> N -  the symbol for nitrogen and an atom of this is small.

for an infix small M

> micro - small and symbol Greek mu which is a letter m.

and, itself, it is only a small O

> [omicron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omicron)  - Greek letter o and literally small o.

The pharaoh: In the tongue of a beautiful pharaoh

> Omicron is a Greek word, but famously beautiful Egyptian Pharoah Cleopatra, daughter of Ptolemy XII, would spoken it as her native tongue was Koine Greek.

Comment: This is it. Well done!